# AngularJs fit ng-grid to page height

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have 1 full-width div on the page with float left.
After this div i have ng-grid. How can i fit it in entire page height (80%) with ability to resize on browser windows resize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a now i've solved this problem by this style on column container:

```
display: table-cell;
```